# Wrong message for closing questions as off-topic

Tags: support, bug, status-completed

I was just reviewing the queue for closing votes, and I noticed that the message displayed in the options for closing as off-topic was:

> off-topic because...
>   This question does not appear to be about **Ubuntu** within the scope defined in the help center.

This appears on the first menu after clicking the "Close" button. The emphasis on the word Ubuntu is mine.

Comment: Can someone else confirm the appearance of this message?

Comment: I just saw "This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center."

Comment: Also, I just saw: "This question does not appear to be about **Information security** within the scope defined in the help center." (emphasis mine). This is curious...

Comment: This was a caching bug that has now been fixed. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207281/wrong-close-reason-bug-everything-must-be-about-video-games) for details.